# TensorFlow restored model returning constant negative prediction

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network

I've trained a CNN model using Google Colab with TensorFlow. It is a pretty basic CNN:

```
def convolutional_neural_network(x):
    weights = {'W_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),
               'W_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 32])),
               'W_conv3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])),
               'W_conv4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 64, 128])),
               'W_conv5': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 128, 128])),
               'W_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([4 * 2 * 128, 1024])),
               'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))}

    biases = {'b_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
              'b_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
              'b_conv3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
              'b_conv4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128])),
              'b_conv5': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128])),
              'b_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
              'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 110, 42, 1])

    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, weights['W_conv1']) + biases['b_conv1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1)

    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv1, weights['W_conv2']) + biases['b_conv2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2)

    conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv2, weights['W_conv3']) + biases['b_conv3'])
    conv3 = maxpool2d(conv3)

    conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv3, weights['W_conv4']) + biases['b_conv4'])
    conv4 = maxpool2d(conv4)

    conv5 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv4, weights['W_conv5']) + biases['b_conv5'])
    conv5 = maxpool2d(conv5)


    fc = tf.reshape(conv5, [-1, 4 * 2 * 128])    
    fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc']) + biases['b_fc']) 
    fc = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_rate)

    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc, weights['out']), biases['out'], name='pred')

    return output
```

And when I test the accuracy it returns ~80%.

So I saved the model and restored in my computer to actually use it in practice. Like so:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('cnn_model.meta')
    new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    pred1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("pred:0")

    print_pred = tf.Print(pred1, [pred1])
    pred = tf.greater(print_pred, 0.5)
    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")
    with driver as dv:
        while(True):
            image = np.array(sct.grab(coordinates))
            image = image[::, 75:615]
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            image = cv2.resize(image, (0, 0), fx=0.1, fy=0.2)
            first_image = np.array(image, dtype='float').reshape(1, 4620)
            if(sess.run(pred, {x: first_image})):
                actions.send_keys(Keys.SPACE).perform()
```

The output of the CNN is turned into a binary "press or not press" the SPACE key.

My problem is, when I run this, the prediction always returns this value: **-0.21995841**

Which is strange given that I'm feeding very similar images as the test and train data sets.

Can someone shed a light on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!